# My MVC Areas logout not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im developing an MVC project, it has two `Areas`, in area 1 the logoff button works fine, but not working for area 2

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="lgoff">
        <li class="helo" style="margin-right:190px; margin-top:30px;">
            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Welcome", style = "color:#ebc424;text-decoration: none; " })
        </li>
        <li class="lgot" style="text-decoration: none; margin-top:5px; ">
            <a  href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" style="text-decoration: none;">
                <img type="image" id="myimage1" src="~/img/log_out.png" style="float:right;  margin-top:-35px;  "  />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

}

controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
}
```

Comment: Explain what is "not working"? Any errors? what's happening? Is your `LogOff` action shared on both areas or do you have one on each area on different controllers?

Comment: Please tell us the areas and controllers that you're working with. And where is the logoff view defined.

Comment: I'm added this logoff to the default layout, its work fine, and after add areas views and areas controller, its not working logoff button

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: Displayed this error  >>> Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Masters/Account/LogOff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right your logoff action method in main area but you are calling it inside of `Masters` area so you need to tell MVC where your action method is:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account",new {area=""} , FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
}
```